# How to make each selected dot indicator have a different color

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a view pager populated with three fragments and tabs are represented as dots. I created a selector with different drawables for selected or default state and it works ok. However for each selected fragment the corresponding dot indicator has to have a different color. For this I implemented the following but color changes set on tabSelectedListener have no effect, colors remain the ones specified in dot_selector file.

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapterWelcome = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapterWelcome);

            final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
                            break;
                    }
                }
       }
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/dot_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

dot_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_indicator_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_indicator_default"/>
</selector>
```

dot_indicator_selected:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

dot_indicator_default:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape
                android:innerRadius="0dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can refer this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

This worked for me in my app

In layout resource

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>
```

In the onCreate method

```
dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);     
addBottomDots(numberOfDotsYouWant);
```

addBottomDots() method

```
private void addBottomDots(int currentPage)
{
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            dots[i].setTextColor(getColor(dot_light));
        else
            dots[i].setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if(dots.length > 0)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getColor(dot_dark));
        else
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Original source is from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

Comment: Yes but I modified it to use it in my viewpagers @Piyush